# iOS15 Xcode 13 Global Accent Color not working

Tags: swiftui, ios15, xcode13

I'm using the latest beta of Xcode 13 with an app for `iOS 14` and now I'm facing this strange issue:
The global accent color of my app was working fine until the `iOS 15` update when the color is now set as the default blue where before it was my custom color.

Here is the asset catalog:
[image]

This is my project settings page where you can see that the accent color is correct.
[image]

And this is what the app looks like when built. The color is the default blue when it needs to be a really dark blue/purple color.
[image]

Comment: We are also seeing this issue in a project that was created with Xcode 12. I tested creating a new project with Xcode 13 and the build setting is honored as expected. Will update with a solution if we find out what’s the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a temporary workaround on [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691336) AppleDeveloperForum Thread

credit to: [@chad_sykes](https://developer.apple.com/forums/profile/chad_sykes) for this answer

> I found an alternate solution, which was to set the .accentColor on the main view in the WindowGroup and it gets used across the app.

```swift
@main
struct CurvApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            myMainView
                .accentColor(CurvGlobalAppearance.curvAccentColor)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helpt me as well. Totally weird that we have tint and accentColor ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

We were using the `UIAppearance` API in our app. We were not setting the tint color, but somehow calling any of the UIAppearance API's after the app has finished launching causes this behavior.

```swift
enum AppAppearance {
    static func configure() {
        configureCustomBarApperance()
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: .primaryBackground)
        UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = nil
        UIScrollView.appearance().keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    }

    static func configureCustomBarApperance() {
        let barAppearance = UIBarAppearance()
        barAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        barAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: .primaryBackground)
        // Toolbars
        let toolbarAppearance = UIToolbarAppearance(barAppearance: barAppearance)
        UIToolbar.appearance().standardAppearance = toolbarAppearance
        UIToolbar.appearance().compactAppearance = toolbarAppearance
        UIToolbar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = toolbarAppearance
        // Navigation Bars
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance(barAppearance: barAppearance)
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes[.foregroundColor] = UIColor.secondaryLabel
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        // Tab Bars
        let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        tabBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: .secondaryBackground)
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    }
}
```

Our solution was to move all of the UIAppearance API work to the initializer of the `AppDelegate` and this fixed the issue for us. So instead of calling `AppAppearance.configure()` after the app finished launching...we call it from `AppDelegate.init` and our Global Accent Color is now being honored.

Don't ask me why...I couldn't tell you.

Comment: that was it: move it to after launch finishes, not inside an init